# Sending a file as multipart parameter with jersey-multipart

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipart, jersey-client

everyone!

I'm trying to send a request to a Rest Service to upload a PDF file, but I'm getting a HTTP Status of 400.

The service allows sending several files, but only one is required. The WADL Definition is:

```
<resource path="/uploadFiles">
<method name="POST" id="uploadDocuments">
    <request>
        <representation mediaType="multipart/mixed">
            <param name="attachment1" style="query" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <param name="attachment2" style="query" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <param name="attachment3" style="query" type="xs:anyType"/>
        </representation>
    </request>
    <response>
        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
    </response>
</method>
```

In my case, I just want to send one file in "attatchment1". I'm using jersey-multipart and I have this method to create the multipart object:

```
private MultiPart createMultiPart (String fileName){

File file = new File(fileName);

final FileDataBodyPart bodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart(fileName, file);

final FormDataContentDisposition dispo = FormDataContentDisposition
            .name("attachment1")
            .fileName(fileName)
            .size(file.length())
            .build();

bodyPart.contentDisposition(dispo);

final MultiPart multBody = new MultiPart().bodyPart(fd);

return multBody;
```

}

This is the client I have to send the request:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client client = new DefaultClientConfig();
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource resource = client.resource(URI);
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.Builder resourceBuilder = resource.getRequestBuilder();
resourceBuilder = resourceBuilder.accept("application/json");
resourceBuilder = resourceBuilder.type("multipart/mixed");
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse response;
response = resourceBuilder.method("POST", com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.class, createMultiPart(fileName));
```

I think the trouble is I have any mistake creating the multiPart object. Does anyone know hoy to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you have enable MultpartFeature for jersey?

Comment: Yes, MultipartFeature is enabled.